# Matching curves to recognize Chinese characters

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to build an application to help people learn how to write Chinese  characters.

There's a project on GitHub called Make Me A Hanzi that has a database of SVG characters, which I've processed to make stroke paths from (basically taking the medians, inspired by http://chanind.github.io/hanzi-writer/). For example: https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi/blob/master/svgs/20070.svg (The word "shu", which means "book"). For some background, there's a proper order of strokes for writing a Chinese/Japanese characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_order).

What I want to do is build an application to help people learn how to write Chinese. I want to present the user with a blank canvas, and then have them write the character, stroke by stroke (think of it like a flashcard app). For each stroke, I want to match it against the canonical stroke from the SVG for similarity, which is where I'm not sure how to proceed. Importantly, in this application the software will know the character that it wants the user to write - so I'm not trying to match their writing against an arbitrary character, but rather a specific one.

I've read about Fréchet distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance), however this doesn't seem to capture the directionality of the curve - a squiggle and a straight light would have a low Fréchet distance but would probably be off by quite a bit. In addition, in written Chinese small variations like a hook (note the hook in the bottom right of the SVG character above) are important, so I want a distance metric that captures this. Likewise, less important is the relative position of the curve - so if they wrote the same character but down and to the left a bit, or too small, I'd want it to be a match.

So my question is - what is a good metric/method for measuring the similarity between two curves (where a curve is say an ordered list of (x, y) points), for this problem of stroke recognition?

Comment: It seems you will also have to compare first and second order derivative characteristics like the normal direction (for the squiggle) and curvature (for the hook).

Comment: That's a good point! I'm going to try representing the stroke as a cubic spline, and then looking at the Fréchet distance of the first and second derivatives.